# Most efficient way to transfer 2D initializer_list to 1D normal array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, loops, optimization

I'm writing a constructor that will transfer elements from a 2D initializer list declared as `initializer_list<initializer_list<T>> myInitializerList` to a 1D normal array declared as `T * arr` (this will store the elements in row-major order). I have two nested `for` loops to iterate over the initializer lists but I'm trying to optimize the test expressions in each `for` loop (the second of the three statements in the loop declaration).

I have a couple ideas for how to do this but I'm not sure which will be faster. The first is to compare iterators and make the test expression for the outer loop `rowItr != myInitializerList.end()` and for the inner loop `colItr != rowItr->end()`.

My second idea involves comparing indexes, not iterators, and it might be faster (although I'm not sure). Below is a complete loop demonstrating how I've implemented the second strategy:

```
template <typename T> //a numerical type
//intentionally left out constructor definition, variable initialization
for (unsigned currentPosition{ 0 }; currentPosition < numRows*numCols; rowItr++) {
    typename initializer_list<T>::iterator colItr = rowItr->begin();
    for (unsigned currentColumn{ 0 }; currentColumn++ < numCols; colItr++) {
        arr[currentPosition++] = *colItr;
    }
}
//end constructor definition
```

The arrays will store numerical types, most likely `float` and have dimensions of up to `1024x1024`.

Based on these constraints, is one technique faster than the other? Alternatively, is there a third algorithm I didn't consider that will be faster than both of the ones I already have?

Comment: The variant with a check against `rowItr->end()` is unfair because it requires the compiler to actually take into account that the inner `initializer_list`s can have different size, while your second variant simply assumes it. Whether you use the iterator/pointers or indices will probably make no difference.

Comment: @eukaryota Thanks for your response. An earlier comment in this thread recommended using foreach loops because they would be more readable than what I already have. My ultimate goal is efficiency and not readability, but if a foreach loop would be just as fast as iterators then I might as well have both. Can you please address this distinction as well as what you've already written in your comment in an official answer to this question? Then I can mark it as an accepted solution.